# Добавление параметра в текущий url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

На сайте есть две формы, 1-я - фильтр товаров, 2-я - сортировка(выпадающий список). Мне нужно что бы при выборе параметров в фильтре я мог производить сортировку по отфильтрованным параметрам.

Сейчас сделал так: в каждой форме добавил hidden_field_tag и в качестве значения указал параметр урл:

```
= hidden_field_tag :color, params[:color]
```

Но такой вариант работает с ошибками(в урл дублируются параметры)

Нашел вариант как все это сделать с помощью ссылки:

```
= link_to 'Сортировка по цвету', root_path(params.merge({color: :white}))
```

Но применить это решение на выпадающий список (select_tag) не получается.

Comment: А сортировка как осуществляется? AJAX? Не очень понятно, почему дублируется параметр, вы к текущему URL его добавляете?

Comment: Без ajax. Да, к текущему урл.

Вылечил дублирование, 

`- if params[:sort].present?
        = hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort]
`

но по моему какой-то велосипед получается)

Comment: Можно сделать одну форму для сортировки и для фильтра. Для этого в теге `select`, с вариантами сортировки нужно указать атрибут `form`, содержащий идентификатор формы фильтра.

Comment: А как указать такой идентификатор?

Comment: Например форма фильтра `<form id="my_filter_form" >...</form>`. Селект с вариантами сортировки `<select form="my_filter_form" >...</select>`